# How to get locale within JSTL with dash as separator?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, dojo, jstl

`PageContext.request.locale` return `Locale` like "en_US"

But current javascript library (Dojo) is seeking something like 'en-us', 'es-es'..etc

Is there any API to use other than customized a javascript function to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The Locale class has a `toLanguageTag()` method that does what you want:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#toLanguageTag()